# Differences in cursor previews

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, icons, desktop-icons

I was looking at some of the system cursors present in `C:\Windows\Cursors` and I saw that there are differences in the previews shown in different places by Windows Explorer

[image]

This has happened on many files. Some files even show a custom cursor (that I made), which is present in a completely unrelated folder, as their Windows Explorer preview
However the preview that comes in `Right Click > Properties` is always correct.

This is Windows 7 Enterprise.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Just to be sure: does this happen with `.cur` files only?

Comment: I just happened to notice this with the cursor files and was curios as to why it was happening. I'm not sure about other files though.

Comment: Try [resetting the icon cache](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-rebuild-the-icon-cache-in-windows-vista/), then log off and log back on. See whether it makes any difference.